# Mac Hibernate Sleep Mode, quiet and no hard drive sounds

Tags: mac, power

I have MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2018, MacOS Monterey 12.1 . Everytime, I press Apple--> Sleep, I sometimes here churning/hard drive sounds. I want to make it so, it goes in totally quiet sleep mode, similar to Microsoft Windows (Hibernate). (Trying to focus on homework and college studies)

How do I do this on Mac? What should I do on Battery Settings ?

[image]

Comment: A MacBook Pro from 2018 would not have a hard drive at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your mac is connected to the power cord, if so, you should check the power adapter section:

- uncheck wake for network access
- uncheck power nap

I had the exact same problem, it would be constantly starting and stopping (in my case, it was the fans), until one day I accidentally knocked the power cord and it fully stopped. Then I got curious and found the settings.

[image]

Comment: this is not working fully, computer is making sounds, I tried going to "sleep" and its still making sounds

Comment: try unplugging the power cord, if that works, then it's some other setting or some app that is authorized by the mac to wake up the computer